# snakemake truncating shell codes

Tags: python, shell, unix, bioinformatics, snakemake

I'm trying to change the chromosome number notation from [0-9XY] to Chr[0-9XY] using the samtools reheader in the shell command of the snakemake.

```
rule rename:
    input:
        os.path.join(config["input"], "{sample}.bam"),
    output:
        os.path.join(config["output"], "new_sample/{sample}_chr.bam")
    log:
        os.path.join(config["log"], "samtools/{sample}")
    shell:
        "samtools view -H {input} | sed  -e 's/SN:\([0-9XY]*\)/SN:chr\1\/' -e 's/SN:MT/SN:chrM/' |samtools reheader - {input} > {output}"
```

The code ran successfully in the terminal but when I used the code in snakemake it gave the error:

```
shell:
        samtools view -H /Users/EGA_dataset/cnvkit_snakemake/input/EGAF00000788153_PD11458c.bam | sed  -e 's/SN:\([0-9XY]*\)/SN:chr/' -e 's/SN:MT/SN:chrM/' |samtools reheader - /Users/cnvkit_snakemake/input/EGAF00000788153_PD11458c.bam > /Users/EGA_dataset/cnvkit_snakemake/output/new_sample/EGAF00000788153_PD11458c_chr.bam
        (one of the commands exited with non-zero exit code; note that snakemake uses bash strict mode!)
```

When I looked into the error I found that the snakemake read the sed  -e **'s/SN:([0-9XY]*)/SN:chr\1/** as **'s/SN:([0-9XY]*)/SN:chr/'**. That is, it truncated the code for some reasons I do not understand.

Comment: cross posted: https://www.biostars.org/p/9501353/

Comment: You have a typo, you can't backslash the final slash in the first substitution `chr\1\/`

Answer (score 1):

I'm reasonably certain this is due to Python treating the backslash as an escape character - you'll need to escape any backslashes you have with another backslash in order for them to be passed through the shell rather than interpreted by Python:

```
rule rename:
    input:
        os.path.join(config["input"], "{sample}.bam"),
    output:
        os.path.join(config["output"], "new_sample/{sample}_chr.bam")
    log:
        os.path.join(config["log"], "samtools/{sample}")
    shell:
        "samtools view -H {input} | sed  -e 's/SN:\\([0-9XY]*\\)/SN:chr\\1\\/' -e 's/SN:MT/SN:chrM/' |samtools reheader - {input} > {output}"
```

(Assuming that escaping the parentheses was what you meant to do.)

Answer (score 0):

@KeyboardCat answer is probably correct but instead of escaping characters, I would use raw string formatting (i.e. `r"..."`) so you don't need to worry about the python interpreter treating backslash and other meta-character in a special way. E.g.:

```
rule rename:
    ...
    shell:
        r"""
        samtools view -H {input} | sed  -e 's/SN:\([0-9XY]*\)/SN:chr\1\/' -e 's/SN:MT/SN:chrM/' |samtools reheader - {input} > {output}
        """
```

Although I kind of doubt that `chr\1` is actually what you want...?